# Difference between Netty and Thrift

Tags: netty, thrift

What is the difference between Netty and Thrift. It seems that they can both allow protocol definition and data transport.
Can someone please provide a better perspective of explaining these two? Very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Netty is a low-level networking library. You can use it to build networking clients and servers. Usually, this means implementing specs or making use of the implementations provided by netty. You could use netty to implement RPC but you would likely be better served by looking for a higher-level abstraction. Netty is JVM only. Protocols in relation to netty, would usually refer to networking standards, things like HTTP, DNS, TLS, etc.

Thrift provides code for clients, servers, and data format, based on a spec that you provide. It does this in an interoperable way across many languages. Tech which could be compared with thrift would be things like swagger code gen, GRPC, protobuf (data only). While netty implements the functionality to transmit the data over the network, thrift would need to rely on a dependency (like netty, although thrift doesn't actually use netty) to do that for it.